# Understanding how the data handling works in production

Tags: django, amazon-s3, heroku, production

I do not really understand how the database works when using in production.
My stack:

- Django
- Heroku
- AWS S3
- PostgresSQL on Heroku

Users can generate some images on my app. The images are saved to AWS S3, and in some feature I want to retrieve the last generated image.

This below is my model where the images are saved in.

models.py:

```
class imgUploadModel(models.Model):
    auto_increment_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, default=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")
```

And here the view where the images is taken again and handled in some features.

view.py:

```
imgname = imgUploadModel.objects.all().last().image
```

As you can see I use `.last()` to get to the latest images which was generated.
Now to my questions:

In production, could it be that one user sees another users images? Or how does the Dynos (from heroku) separate the sessions?
Since the AWS S3 bucket is just a memory storage without dividing it by users, I assume that one user can see other users images. Especially then, when user A creates an Img, and user B clicks on 'latest image'.

If it is so, how can I create Dynos or Buckets or anything else to prevent this behaviour.
I just do not really understand it from a logical point of view.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Heroku, and very little to do with Amazon S3. These technologies aren't magic. If uploads are supposed to be user-specific, _your app_ needs to take that into account. Should your image model have an `owned_by` field, for example? Do you need to prevent users from seeing other users' images if they guess a relevant URL, or do you just not want to show them by default? In the latter case you'll want to change your query. In the former case, things get trickier.

Comment: Note that your app running locally will have the same issues. You probably just haven't encountered them since you've been developing and testing as a single user.